# Is it necessary to add related objects to the context before saving?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, datacontext

I'm getting some unexpected behavior from the Entity Framework and I'd like to verify if my expectations are wrong or if I should suspect that the system is configured in a flawed way.

There's an entity *Master* and one of its fields is a list of *Minion* type. In the DB, they correspond to two tables related to each other by a primary key.

In the program, I fetch a pre-existing master from the DB and I add a new minion to it. Since I'm outside of the context at that moment, I create me one and add the master that the minion's been added to like so.

```
using (ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
{
  context.Masters.AddOrUpdate(master);
  foreach (Minion minion in master.Minions)
    context.DirectDebitStatus.AddOrUpdate(minion);
  int count = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Count();
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'd expect the foreach loop to be unnecessary as the added instances of *Minion* should be recognized by Entity Framework and added to the database accordingly. However, it's not the case and I'm uncertain why. I suspect that there's something else wrong but before I start spending a lot of time chasing the problem, I'd like to make sure that it's not a goose chase but a bug chase.

Comment: Yes, your expectation is correct - you should not have to add the minions. Adding the `master` and saving should also save any minions associated with that master.

Comment: @Peter Awesomely clear. Now, apparently the EF doesn't view them as associated. Any suggestions on how to investigate why? I shouldn't need to add the minion after the master's been added to the context's collection, should I? And it doesn't matter that the master is pre-existing while the minion is created during the process, does it?

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to say without seeing more or the surrounding code. Where is `master` coming from? It's possible if master is disconnected and minions are added to it that using `AddOrUpdate()` will not add or update the minions.

Comment: What does AddOrUpdate do? I suspect it changes the EntityState, which it only does for this Entry and this Entry alone. When you want to Add navigation properties as well, you'll have to Use the DbSet<T>().Add()-Method. Manipulation of entity states does work well if you want to add an entry, but NOT the navigation property - in my project, I do it like that all the time to not have any nasty side effects.